# How to connect Wix Database to my Xcode project?

Tags: swift, database, xcode, firebase, velo

hey few weeks backs I decided I wanted to learn to write code and understand the basics of it. The reason behind it is that I want to create an iOS app for my current online business. My business is all digital and I run my website through Wix. So as as I was dabbling with Xcode and learning the swift language, I though I found a way to create a super simple app, that would just display my mobile website using a simple WebKit View. It looked pretty good to me and it worked perfectly.

However when I sent the app for review to the App Store they rejected it because since I was selling digital content I was not allowed "to provide access to external payment mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app".

So as I continue to learn more and more I found out that you can use Google's Firebase databases to create a log in method within your app. However, since my business is all through wix, I was wondering if there is a way that you can connect Wix's data bases to Xcode the same way that you can connect Firebase to Xcode? or is there a way that I can connect the Wix's database to Firebase and then have them interact directly through my Xcode project?

I apologize in advance If I am using wrong terminology. I have been working on this for a few weeks but I am eager to learn more. I would really appreciate some guidance. thank you.

Comment: Hi there, the solution to this is make a app that not have any link or redirect to screen payment. If you look at Spotfy, they dont have any purchase and mention of it inside the app and Apple Store description. That way Apple cant deny your app because of it. They can deny about other things. But, follow the [Apple oficial documentation about](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#business)

Comment: Hey Daniel, Thank you for your time. This is exactly what I am trying to do, but for that I would need an authentication log in page so my paid users are able to use the log in information to log directly into the app and access their content. But I don't know how to connect my wix's database to the Xcode project. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, but need to write some code and show us to try to help with your code.